# socket.js works in dev mode but fails to connnect in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using Nextjs 13.4.13 and socketio works on dev mode perfectly fine but fails to connect from frontend to backend in production.

I am connecting the backend server (`pages/api/socket.ts`) which looks like this:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export default function handler(req: any, res: any) {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("Socket is already running");
    res.end();
    return;
  } else {
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server, {
      path: "/api/socket_io",
      addTrailingSlash: false,
    }); 
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on("connection", (socket: any) => {
      // const room = Array.from(socket.rooms)[1];
      socket.on("join", function (room: any) {
        socket.join(room);

        //etc... etc... connections
      });
    });
  }

  console.log("server started well");
  res.end();
}
```

and am trying to connect it to the frontend like this:

```
const socketInitializer = async () => {
    await fetch("/api/socket");

    socket = io(undefined as any, {
      path: "/api/socket_io",
    });

    socket.on("connect", (s: any) => {
      socket.emit("join", id);
    });

    //connections so on...
}
```

For some reason it works fine on dev but not on production mode.